# Browser addon development

Tags: browser, add-on

Are there any good websites for instructing how to write browser addon for IE, firefox, chrome and Safari?

Not sure whether writing there is some frameworks which can be used to write addon for all major browsers such that one sourcecode for all major browsers.

Thanks.

Comment: No, there is no framework that will build an addon for all major browsers. What are you trying to do? If you need something that will work in all browsers, you could make a web application.

Comment: http://crossrider.com/ is the one you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

IE and Firefox have *very* different plug-in models. IE supports binary helper objects (your native code running in IE's processes). Here’s how you can build one: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/04/04/designing-for-add-on-performance.aspx, 
here’s why you should spend as little of your users’ time as possible in your code: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/03/23/updates-to-add-on-performance-advisor.aspx